# Match multiple patterns in xml file, copy and change the matched lines with awk, sed

Tags: awk, sed

I want to match multiple patterns in xml files, copy and modify the matched lines.
The xml format is in a multi-line pattern,

```
<security-role-assignment>
...
</security-role-assignment>
```

which are on separate lines (not on the same line).
I want to duplicate the block that contains the string "beanA_users" within the multi-line pattern, then replace the duplicated block with:

```
s#beanA_users#beanB_users#
s#runas_a#runas_b#
```

My environment have awk, sed, grep, but not xml_grep nor xmlstarlet.

```
awk -V
GNU Awk 5.0.0, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0, GNU MP 6.2.1).
```

in.xml

```
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanA_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_a</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

out.xml

```
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanA_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_a</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanB_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_b</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

in2.xml

```
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanXYZ_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_test</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanA_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_a</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanC_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_c</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

out2.xml

```
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanXYZ_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_test</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanA_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_a</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanB_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_b</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanC_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_c</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

e.g.

```
awk -f test.awk in.xml > out.xml
awk -f test.awk in2.xml > out2.xml
```

test.awk (this is my best version so far, still need a lot of work)

```
/<security-role-assignment>/ {
   xmlbuf = xmlbuf $0 ORS
   gsub(/beanA_users/,"beanB_users",xmlbuf)
   gsub(/runas_a/,"runas_b",xmlbuf)
   print; next
}
xmlbuf!="" {
   printf "%s", xmlbuf
   xmlbuf=""
}
{ print }
```

Comment: Showing the block of text you want to match on stand-alone isn't nearly as useful for demonstrating your problem or testing a potential solution as showing the block in context surrounded by other, preferably similar, text you do not want to change.

Comment: @Ed Morton, you are right. Thank you for your comment.
in.xml and out.xml are the simplest input and output test files which I am trying to get a awk program to work. I am learning awk, so start with something very simple.
in2.xml and out2.xml are the minimum input and output test files which I just added. I should have clarified my requirement. My apologies.

Comment: Really think about what might be hard for a script to handle then provide THAT as your sample input/output. For example, off the top of my head, a partial match like `<role-name>FOObeanA_users</role-name>` or a match in the wrong place like `<beanA_users>fluffy_users</beanA_users>` or `<role-name>foo</role-name>  <!-- Not <role-name>beanA_users</role-name> -->`. I expect there are others you could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

```
# if your strings are static
# beanA_users#beanB_users
# runas_a#runas_b    
# Try this
$ awk 'NR!=FNR{gsub(/beanA_users/,"beanB_users"); gsub(/runas_a/,"runas_b")}1' in.xml in.xml

<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanA_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_a</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanB_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_b</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -z 's/.*/&&/;s/\(bean\)[[:alpha:]]/\1B/2;s/\(runas_\)[[:alpha:]]/\1b/2' input_file
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanA_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_a</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
<security-role-assignment>
    <role-name>beanB_users</role-name>
    <principal-name>runas_b</principal-name>
</security-role-assignment>
```